# 2-Dimensional NFourierTransform

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

Mathematica `FourierSeries` package contains the `NFourierTransform` function for calculating 1-D Fourier integral numerically.

What is the best approach for calculting 2D Fourier integral numerically? 
Should I simply use the `NIntegrate`? If so, what is the best `Method`?

The example of the transform I am interested in is the following:

```
FourierTransform[1/(x^2 - 2 y^2 - 5 + 5 I), {x, y}, {fx, fy}]
```

Comment: Are you sure in the function? I has sharp long non-decaying tails: [img](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yEc9J.png). It it very difficult to numerically integrate this function.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. This is the function I need to integrate. Besides, I am interested in the analytic solution as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952480/2d-fourier-transfrom-of-1-x2-y2q

Comment: Actually, I can reduce this integral to 1D Fourier transform by calculating the integral with respect to `x` analytically. However, the convergence of the `y`-integral will still be rather poor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
a = -2;
b = 5 I - 5;
f[x_, y_] := 1/(x^2 + a y^2 + b);
```

have long and sharp tails

```
Plot3D[Re[f[x, y]], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

However there is a common procedure to calculate the Fourier transform numerically. It is tricky from the first sight but it is quite obvious if you apply this technique several times. Two main ideas:

1. Use the discrete fast Fourier transform.
2. Use a window function.

Let us discretize from `-R` to `R` with the step `d` over `x` and `y`

```
R = 100.;
d = 0.1;

x = Join[-Reverse@#, Rest@#] &@Range[0., R, d];
n = Length@x;
m = (n - 1)/2;
k = π/(d m) Range[0. - m, m];
X = ConstantArray[x, n];
Y = Transpose@X;

F = f[X, Y];
W = # Transpose@# &@ConstantArray[BlackmanWindow[x/R/2], n];
```

Capital letters mean 2D arrays of values. Here `W` is a window. It smoothly cuts of the function and reduces Gibbs oscillations. `BlackmanWindow` is a good choice, but you can choose many other [window functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WindowFunctions.html).

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {X, Y, F, W}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True}

All our arrays are packed so everything will be calculated very fast.

Without the window our function have the long tails

```
F // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

The tails are reduced with the window

```
F W // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

The Fourier transform and the interpolation

```
fF = d^2 RotateRight[#, {m, m}] &@
     Fourier[#, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}] &@RotateLeft[F W, {m, m}];

res = ListInterpolation[Transpose[fF], {k, k}];

Plot3D[Im@res[kx, ky], {kx, -5, 5}, {ky, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {kx, ky}]
```

[image]

Now we can compare our numerical result with the exact formula which I propose on [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/957410/114218)

```
exact[kx_, ky_] := 2 π BesselK[0, Sqrt[b (kx^2 + ky^2/a)]]/Sqrt[a]

Plot3D[Im@exact[kx, ky], {kx, -5, 5}, {ky, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, AxesLabel -> {kx, ky}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Re@res[kx, 1], Re@exact[kx, 1]}, {kx, -3, 3}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> 2, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Im@res[kx, 1], Im@exact[kx, 1]}, {kx, -3, 3}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> 2, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Everything are the same (except the sharp peaks due to the finite discretization)!

Comment: Very nice exposition, thanks! I seem to have however a problem using this for a couple of specific examples in [Multidimensional DFT of function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149195/multidimensional-dft-of-function)